# How to hide a block based on content type?

Tags: blocks, nodes

I have a custom content type where when loaded, I want to HIDE (no show) a regions block. Been looking around trying to find the answer and have come up short. Ideally, I'd want to do it in a preprocess or something, not within a template. Tried accomplishing it with Context, but appears that only allows you to add blocks to regions, not remove them. Fairly new to Drupal, so bare with me.

Comment: Should this block be displayed in all pages except a specific set of content type pages? or should it be displayed only in node pages corresponding to specific content types?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it is not yet part of Context to negate the context (that I am aware of).

You have 2 options (slightly different than the link mentioned by @Mołot):

1. Write your own context.  It's actually not that hard, and you can follow the general flow suggested in (this post)[http://dtek.net/blog/extending-drupals-context-module-custom-condition-based-field-value].
2. Use the built-in visibility settings on the block configuration page to enable the block on all content types but the one you want, and all pages desireable (e.g, `user/*`, views pages, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Display Suite Extras (comes with [Display Suite)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) allows you to do this. Context will also allow you to do it, but it is theme-dependent (not all themes can allow it, and not for all regions).

Answer (score 0):

When PHP filter is enabled you can set the visibility by PHP code. Then you can do the following to hide the block when viewing a node of a special type:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node->type == 'CONTENTTYPE') {
  return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
```